# Efficiency of explicit call vs lookup of parent function

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Assume we have the following hierarchy:

```
function Parent() {}
Parent.prototype.aFunc = function() {}

function Child() {}
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
```

In this situation, if we create a `Child` object and called `child.aFunc()`, would it be more efficient to allow lookup of parent function, or would an explicit call to the parent's function be better? Like this:

```
Child.prototype.aFunc = function() {
    Parent.prototype.aFunc.call(this);
}
```

Comment: If you don't need to override the behavior of `aFunc` in `Child`, there is no need for the code in the second snippet

Comment: Have a look at ES6 classes and the super keyword: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Super_class_calls_with_super

Comment: @nils `super` desugars quite exactly into the given code, it should not affect the efficiency

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure whether the question is about performance or best practice.

Comment: @nils In either case, the solution is too leave out the extra method…

Comment: The question is related to performance. Was just wondering if explicitly calling the parent function would be more efficient due to directing the method lookup immediately to the parent. I had read that prototype chains can become expensive, but as Bergi also mentioned, it seems engines have optimized for this now.

Answer (score 0):

The explicit parent method lookup and invocation is just an extra lookup and an extra call, I don't see a reason why it would perform better than calling it directly. (Admittedly the cost of lookups is near zero in with optimisations in recent engines).

You'll need to benchmark the two approaches in your specific setting however if you care about exact results.